# QMdiSubWindow titlebar color

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to change the QMdiSubWindow title bar color
and I found a solution posted by eyllanesc using qproxystyle which looks amazing
but the program exits with an error code
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
something related to QProxyStyle I think

here is eyllanesc solution

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def create_icon_by_color(color):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(512, 512)
    pixmap.fill(color)
    return QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)


class TitleProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawComplexControl(self, control, option, painter, widget=None):
        if control == QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_TitleBar:
            if hasattr(widget, "titleColor"):
                color = widget.titleColor
                if color.isValid():
                    option.palette.setBrush(
                        QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QtGui.QColor(color)
                    )
            option.icon = create_icon_by_color(QtGui.QColor("transparent"))
        super(TitleProxyStyle, self).drawComplexControl(
            control, option, painter, widget
        )


class MdiSubWindow(QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=QtCore.Qt.Widget):
        super(MdiSubWindow, self).__init__(parent, flags)
        style = TitleProxyStyle(self.style())
        self.setStyle(style)
        self._titleColor = QtGui.QColor()
@property
def titleColor(self):
    return self._titleColor

@titleColor.setter
def titleColor(self, color):
    self._titleColor = color
    self.update()


class Mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mywindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Customized style")
        self.mdiarea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiarea)
        self.mdiarea.setWindowTitle("Test")

    self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.window.setMinimumSize(160, 120)

    sw = MdiSubWindow()
    sw.setWindowTitle("Test")
    sw.titleColor = QtGui.QColor("lightgray")
    sw.setWidget(self.window)
    self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(sw)


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("Fusion")
view = Mywindow()
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The proxy takes ownership of any base-style object passed to it. However, when the proxy is deleted, it seems the base-style isn't also deleted properly, which causes a core-dump on exit. This bug occurs in both PyQt and PySide. The only work-around I can find is to pass the name of the base-style instead: `style = TitleProxyStyle(self.style().objectName())`.

Comment: works well , but after digging around stylesheets and proxy cant work with each others, do you have a better solution for mdisubwindows

Comment: Just use the proxy to draw everything. I don's see any need to use a stylesheet for the subwindow itself.

Comment: @HoussamFarag What stylesheets are you trying to use that affect the proxy style of the MDI subwindow? And how are you setting it?

Comment: i tried to apply any stylesheet , and the behavior was always strange , try to apply just background for mdiarea,  self.mdiarea.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue") and it will give same error on exit Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution using stylesheet

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mywindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Customized style")
        self.mdiarea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiarea)
        self.mdiarea.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.window.setMinimumSize(160, 120)

        sw = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
        sw.setWindowTitle("Test")
        sw.titleColor = QtGui.QColor("lightgray")
        sw.setWidget(self.window)
        self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(sw)
        sw.setStyleSheet("""QMdiSubWindow {selection-background-color: red;}""")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    view = Mywindow()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```